# Android: regarding start and close time in the database with same values which is last selecting

Tags: android, database

- I am creating a database `TIMES`. In it, I create 3 fields: `id`,`starttime` and `closetime`.

  -Now my problem is that when I click the starttime first and then `closetime`, the database stores only the `closetime` value in both the fields. When I choose the close button first and then choose the start button, the database stores the `starttime` value in both fields.

  -Here is my code:

  ```
  btnOpenTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {  
          showStartTimePicker();
      }
  });
  ```

  AFTER I CALL showStartTimePicker() method:

  private void showStartTimePicker() {
          TimePickerDialog tdialog;
          if (mTimeStart == null) {
              final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

  ```
          tdialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeStartSetListener,
                  c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);

      } else {
          tdialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeStartSetListener,
                  mTimeStart.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                  mTimeStart.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
      }
      tdialog.show();
  }
  ```

Comment: if you are not able to show it properly then i send you a link which show proper format for the code..                                            "http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/556645/QueryplusRegardingplusaddplustheplustimesplusinplu"

Comment: This is unreadable. Post the code in the question (you can edit the question) and remove the comments.

Comment: OK otherwise i share a link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/556645/QueryplusRegardingplusaddplustheplustimesplusinplu

Comment: You would be well-served by reading about StackOverflow Markdown formatting. WHen you added the code to the question you completely botched the formatting. Good rule of thumb: Spaces, not tabs (4 to begin code blocks, 4 for each indentation).